# change file size format when using stat

Tags: command-line, files, ls, coreutils, stat

The formatting character `%s` makes `stat` print the filesize in bytes

```
# stat -c'%A %h %U %G %s %n' /bin/foo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 45112 /bin/foo
```

`ls` can be configured to print the byte size number with "thousand-separator", i.e. `45,112` instead of the usual `45112`.

```
# BLOCK_SIZE="'1" ls -lA 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 45,112 Nov 15  2014
```

Can I format the output of stat similarly, so that the file size has thousand-separator?

The reason why I am using `stat` in the first place is, I need to output like `ls`, but without time, therefore `-c'%A %h %U %G %s %n'`.

Or is there some other way to print the `ls`-like output without the time?

Comment: On what operating system? Should we assume Linux?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Specify the date format, but leave it empty eg.

```
ls -lh --time-style="+"
```

Produces

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 christian christian 8.5K  a.out
drwxrwxr-x 2 christian christian 4.0K  sock
-rw-rw-r-- 1 christian christian  183  t2.c
```

Answer (score 4):

On a GNU system, you can use the `'` flag of GNU `printf`:

```
$ stat -c"%A %h %U %G %'s %n" /bin/foo  
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 45,112 /bin/foo
```

This is documented in `man 3 pritnf`:

```
'      For decimal conversion (i, d, u, f, F, g, G) the output is to be grouped
       with  thousands'  grouping  characters if the locale information indicates
       any. Note that many versions of gcc(1) cannot parse this option and will 
       issue a warning.  (SUSv2 did not include %'F, but SUSv3 added it.)
```

Alternatively, you can parse it in yourself:

```
$ stat --printf="%A\t%h\t%U\t%G\t%s\t%n\n" a | rev | 
    awk '{gsub(/.../,"&,",$2); print}' | rev
-rwxr-xr-x 2 terdon terdon 4,096 file
```

Comment: Wow! I learnt something new today!

Comment: Please replace 4,5112 by 45,112 - thousands are separated, not ten thousands.

Comment: @Ned64 thanks. Obviously, I wrote that one manually :)

Comment: @terdon It was also wrong in the original question, which I edited (might still be under review).